# Replace html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok guys, let's suppose I have one html form with 2 fields like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <p><label>Login<br><input type="text" class="inpText" name="user" id="user"/> </label><span class="provider">@isp.com</span></p>
    <p><label>Password<br><input type="password" class="inpText inpPass" name="pass" id="pass"/></label></p>
</fieldset>
```

Now, I need to replace the entire code inside the < fieldset > - < /fieldset>.
Remove both inputs, or add how many inputs I need, or just write one < p > inside the < fieldset>, or whatever, I just need to replace the code between 2 'flags'; in this case the fieldset. How to do that using javascript? JQuery is acceptable too, but I prefer javascript only if possible.
Thank you.

Comment: You would use DOM manipulation functions. See [jQuery DOM manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Comment: This is ***basic*** jquery. Please do a little research...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the fieldset an id and do $('#fieldset_id').html('html to replace with');, or with plain js use document.getElementById('fieldset_id').innerHTML = 'html to replace with';

Comment: I can't give the fieldset an id, because I'm working with a javascript injected in the page via chrome extension... I just need to locate the flag before, the flag after, and then change the content between the 2 flags...

Comment: if it's the only fieldset, use var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[0];

Comment: I'm trying: `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('fieldset')[0];
elements.innerHTML('<p><label>Senha Cartão<br><input type="password" class="inpText inpPass" name="pass" id="pass"/></label></p>');`
Still not working...

Comment: you're setting the innerHTML incorrectly, that was my mistake in the first post. it's elements.innerHTML = 'html to replace with' - see this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/85n9a/

Answer (score 1):

Well if jQuery is acceptable:

```
$("fieldset").html("NEW HTML HERE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `fieldset` an id and then use `document.getElementById("fieldSetId")` to get the fieldset. You can then alter it with `innerHTML` property.

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/vF7Xb/

Comment: I can't give the fieldset an id, because I'm working with a javascript injected in the page via chrome extension... I just need to locate the flag before, the flag after, and then change the content between the 2 flags...